# In PowerShell, files written using echo command aren't working with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, linux, powershell, terminal, echo

`echo "console.log('Test success!')" > app.js`

`node app`

Runs fine on Linux. PowerShell, however, produces the following error message:

```
~\apps\test\app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��c
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

On the other hand, if I were to `echo > app.js`, then input `console.log('Test success!')` from a text editor. `node app` runs just fine everywhere.

How come?

My best guess: In PowerShell, echo seems to make strings hexadecimal and not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell's `>` operator invariably produces *UTF-16LE*-encoded files**, which `node` cannot handle.

To create UTF-8-encoded files instead, use `Out-File` or `Set-Content` with `-Encoding Utf8`:

```
"console.log('Test success!')" | Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 app.js
```

Note that PowerShell invariably prepends a [pseudo-BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) (the first 3 bytes are hex. byte values `EF BB BF`) when creating UTF-8 files, which is only used in the *Windows* world, but `node` seems to be able to handle that, both on Windows and Unix-like platforms.

Comment: Spot on! Verified using `file *` in bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is dependent on the shell that you are using. In Windows, if you are using the standard command prompt, cmd.exe, the quotes themselves will be included. So app.js will contain this:

"console.log('Test success!')"

Removing the quotes will give the expected outcome.

echo console.log('Test success!') > app.js

Note that if you run this on PowerShell or Linux, you will get different results since those shells handle quotes differently.

Comment: Totally right. I'll clarify that this happens in Powershell.